# $z^2-1$ has infinitely many roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

I'm thinking about the fundamental theorem of algebra. It says: Let $F$ any field and $p(x)\in F[x]$ then there is an extension $K$ such that $p(x)$ has $n$ roots over $K$ ¿Does it mean has maximum $n$ roots ? Think in the polynomial $z^2−1$ over complex numbers, it has infinitely many roots because of $z=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ is a root but $\theta$ could be any real number except $0$. I mean $z$ could be any complex number over the circle with center $0$ and radius $1$. I'm asking about this because of I've found in many sites that fundamental theorem of algebra guarantees there are at most n roots and if a polynomial has infinitely many roots then it is the zero polynomial. Thanks

Comment: $\pm 1$ are the only roots. What makes you think that $|z|=1$ implies $z^{2}=1$?

Comment: I think you are assuming $x^2 = |x|^2$ which is true if $x$ is real. (Because $x = \pm |x|$ and $(\pm |x|)^2 = |x|^2)$  But if $z$ is complex then $z = |z| (\cos\theta + i\sin \theta)$ for some theta and $z^2 = |z|^2(\cos\theta + i\sin \theta)^2$ but $(\cos\theta + i\sin \theta)^2 \ne 1$ (unless $(\cos\theta + i\sin \theta) =\pm 1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ is a solution to $|z^2| = 1$.  But it is *not* a solution to $z^2 =1$.

I think you are confused because if $x$ is real then $|x^2| = x^2$.  But that is because if $x$ is real then we must have either $x = 1\cdot |x|$ or $x =-1\cdot |x|$.  And either way $x^2 = (\pm 1)^2|x|^2$ and $|\pm 1|^2 = 1$.

In complex numbers that just isn't true.

In complex numbers $z$ may equal $|z|(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)$ for any angle $\theta$ (*including* $0$... why did you leave $0$ out?).  ANd so $z^2 = |z|^2(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)^2$.  But $(\cos\theta + i\sin)^2 = (\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2\theta) + 2i\cos\theta \sin\theta$ and *that* does not *have* to equal $1$.  (It *could* equal $1$ if $\theta = 0$ or $\pi$; and its *absolute value* is $1$; but it, itself, doesn't equal $1$ if $\theta \ne 0$ or $\pi$.)

The only two solutions to $z^2 -1 = 0$ are $z^2 =1$ so $z =\pm 1$.

There are infinitely many solutions to $|z|^2 -1 = 0$.  But there are only !$2$! solutions to $z^2 -1 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$z^2-1=0$$
$$z=re^{ix}$$
$$r^2e^{2ix}=1$$
then since $|e^{2ix}|=1$ we must have $r^2=1$ and so $r=1$ since $r>0$
and so now we are solving:
$$e^{2ix}=1$$
notice that for this we want $2x=2n\pi$ and so $x=n\pi$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ so yes there are infinitely many roots in the polar form but if we view the complex solutions as vector numbers then there are two $\pm1$